# How to transform string to class object? C# WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem, as a field of a class, I wrote down the type of data as a link to the class (public Picture pictureName) and I need to take the data from textbox(or combobox it doesn't matter) and to save it in this field. However, I don't understand how i need to transform this data to be in a string type. It's a course work without db(oh gosh), please, if you know, help me. 
And the error(can't transform from string to Artist) is on the line with:

```cs
pctrs.authorName = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
```

```cs
public class Picture
    {
        public Artist authorName { get; set; }
        public string pictureName { get; set; }
        public string pictureGenre { get; set; }
        public int pictureYear { get; set; }
        public string drawingMaterial { get; set; }
        public string pictureSize { get; set; }
        public string displayMethod { get; set; }

        public Picture(Artist authorName, string pictureName, string pictureGenre, int pictureYear, string drawingMaterial, string pictureSize, string displayMethod)
        {
            this.authorName = authorName;
            this.pictureName = pictureName;
            this.pictureGenre = pictureGenre;
            this.pictureYear = pictureYear;
            this.drawingMaterial = drawingMaterial;
            this.pictureSize = pictureSize;
            this.displayMethod = displayMethod;
        }
        public Picture() : this(authorName: null, pictureName: "non", pictureGenre: "non", pictureYear: 0, drawingMaterial: "non", pictureSize: "non", displayMethod: "non") { }
    }
```

```cs
            Picture pctrs = new Picture();
            List<Picture> newPictures = new List<Picture>();
            try
            {
                pctrs.authorName = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
                foreach (Picture p in art.pictures)
                {
                    if (pctrs.authorName == p.authorName)
                    {
                        int k = art.pictures.IndexOf(p);
                        newPictures.Add(art.pictures[k]);
                        pictureBindingSource.DataSource = newPictures;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                newPictures = art.pictures;
            }
            pictureBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            art.isChangeData = true;
            art.Load();
            toolStripMenuItem22.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please post your code as code in your question so it's easier for people to answer :)

Comment: Hi. It looks like you're trying to assign a string object `toolStripTextBox1.Text` to a property of type `Artist` (authorName).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of `toolStripTextBox1.Text` is a string. You want to assign this string to `Picture.AuthorName`:

```
Picture pctrs = new Picture();
pctrs.authorName = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
```

The problem is: `AuthorName` is not a string, despite its identifier, it is an `Artist`. So either you have to change the type of property `AuthorName`, or you have to find a method to convert a string to an `Artist`:

```
class Picture
{
    public string AuthorName {get; set;}
    ...
}

Picture picture = new Picture();
picture.authorName = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
```

Or a Procedure to convert a string to Artist:

```
Artis CreateArtist(string artistName)
{
    return new Artist
    {
        Name = artistName,
        ...
    }
}

Picture picture = new Picture();
picture.authorName = CreateArtist(toolStripTextBox1.Text);
```

Well, I don't know your Artist class, but I think you get the gist.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the implementation of `Picture`, I think `Picture.authorName` needs to be of type string.

```
public Artist authorName { get; set; }
```

since authorName is of type `Artist`, you need to create a instance of Artist and set  toolStripTextBox.Text's value to it's correct property.

for example:

```
pctrs.authorName = new Artist();
pctrs.authorName.SomePropertyYouWantToSetOnArtist = toolStripTextBox1.Text;
```